# Joining and comparing begin date and an end date of two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm still fairly new to Oracle SQL and I had unsuccessfully implemented this instance at work. Could someone show me how to query this instance?

I've attached a link that shows the tables: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pilvb.jpg
The tables consist of Subprogram, Program, and Results. I think the images are better explain it rather than me explaining every instance.

---

I would like to join a table based on two date columns in two tables: begin dates (Subprogram.SUB_BEGIN_DT & Program.PROG_BEGIN_DT) and end dates (Subprogram.SUB_END_DT & Program.SUB_END_DT). So the gist of it is that in order for a case to have a worker (program.worker_name), the subprogram's running dates (subprogram.sub_begin_dt & subprogram.sub_end_dt) must be in between the Program's running date (Program.Prog_Begin_Dt & Program.PROG_END_DT). Else, it returns NULL for worker.

In addition, the "NULL" value displayed in date columns means that the program is still ongoing.

Thanks

---

Additional details from other's comments and suggestions:
Apologizes for not being clear. If a subprogram's dates falls within the program's date, it would display a worker. I guess I should clarify that whoever is the worker for the program is also the worker for the subworker if the subworker program dates is within the program's date. Also, if the program date is the 8th to null, which means ongoing, and the subprogram date is 9th and 12th, or the subprogram date is 9th and ongoing (null), then it would have a worker.

Also in the imgur link, the RESULT table is the results I hope to see.

Comment: Would you please update your answer to show sample data as text tables (or create/insert statements), and expected output in the same format. This makes it really easier for others to help out.

Comment: Just to be clear, if the sub program's end dates fall both within AND without the program it ties to on CASE_ID, you do NOT want this to show up in the result set?  I.E. if a program goes from the 4th to the 7th, and the joined sub-program goes from the 6th to the 8th, the fact that part of it falls outside the date range means that no worker should show?

Comment: Apologizes for not being clear. Your example is correct. If a subprogram's dates falls within the program's date, it would display a worker. I guess I should clarify that whoever is the worker for the program is also the worker for the subworker if the subworker program dates is within the program's date. Also, if the program date is the 8th to null, which means ongoing, and the subprogram date is 9th and 12th, or the subprogram date is 9th and ongoing (null), then it would have a worker.

Comment: Also, in the imgur link above, the RESULT table is what I would hope to see.

Comment: So, the sub_program's start_date needs to be >= the program's start_date, and the sub_program's end_date needs to be either <= the program's end_date, or the program's end_date and the sub_program's end_date need to both be null.  I guess my confusion is, since your expected-results image shows that you want ALL of the sub_program's rows, with only 1 additional column (which is either NULL or the joined name from program), why are the table name's not reversed?  It seems that the program table's values are the ones dependent on another table

Comment: Appreciate your response. Yes, what you interpreted about the filters are correct. The results expected are workers working the subprogram, and if the workers are working the program, it would automatically make them the worker for the subprogram. I get what you mean by the confusion. The data tables I'm working with are full of discrepancies unfortunately. Not that it matters to the answer, but there are instances where the individual will be assigned and approved for a subprogram case days before they get approved for the program itself. That's another long story.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm unserstanding it right, you might be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT sp.CASE_ID, sp.SUB_BEGIN_DT AS BEGIN_DATE_SP, sp.SUB_END_DATE AS END_DATE_SP,
        sp.NAME, sp.SUBPROGRAM, p.WORKER_NAME
FROM Subprogram sp
LEFT OUTER JOIN Program p
ON sp.CASE_ID = p.CASE_ID
    AND sp.SUB_BEGIN_DT >= p.PROG_BEGIN_DT
    AND ((sp.SUB_END_DT <= p.PROG_END_DT)
         OR
         (sp.SUB_END_DT IS NULL AND p.PROG_END_DT IS NULL)
        )
```